# traverse dynamic number of options in json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am building an MCQ application which has multiple questions with varying number of options. 
So, question 1 can have 4 options and question 2 can have 2 options and so on.

I have generated a json array from backend which gives me data which tells me about the number of options each question has.

But i am stuck on the part of displaying this options on browser.

My Json Object looks like this:

```
[
{
    "option1": "asdasd",
    "option2": "ajda",
    "option3": "hsadb",
    "option4": "asd",
    "question": "hello",
    "quest_id": 32
},
{
    "option1": "dsf",
    "option2": "afs",
    "question": "asdad",
    "quest_id": 34
}
]
```

I want to display dynamically each question with their corresponding options and radio buttons besides them.

Also i have an array which tells me the number of options in each like [4,2] which says question 1 has 4 options and question 2 has 2 options.
I tried to apply ng-repeat using angular JS in this array but it gives "dupes error" as duplicate elements are not allowed.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `for...in` to traverse over object members

Comment: If you want to use ng-repeat  then the dupes error can be solved just write track by $index. e.g.<div ng-repeat="a in data track by $index"></div>

Comment: @shatakshi if i use track by $index , it will not use the values right?

Comment: Ofcourse it will use values.just give it a try

Answer (score 0):

`{test:[{question: "hello", answers:['asda','asdasd','asdasd'], "quest_id": 32}]}`
use a structure like this and the ng-repeat should look like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="question in test">
{{question.question}}
<div ng-repeat="obj in question.answers">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="testResult[question.quest_id].answer" value="obj">
</div>
```

something like this should work